# Node.js Uploading an Image from Single Page App

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, single-page-application

I'm using `express.js 3.5.1` as the backend for my app. It's just a basic forum, but I want my users to be able to upload images. I can't use a simple form to upload since it will cause a redirect. The only solution I've found that seems like it may be possible is with [socketio-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socketio-file-upload). I'm hesitant about including `socket.io` just for the sake of uploading images though. Is there any way to do this with a simple `XMLHttpRequest` or `Ajax` request? Or maybe another method I'm not thinking of?

Here's the server code I currently have to handle the incoming request from a form:

```
app.post('/save-image', checkSession, function(req, res)
{
    actionLog( req.session.username, 'is trying to upload a file' );

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files)
        {
    console.log(files);
    res.send({ error: 'not setup yet'
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having had to do with my request router and not the requests themselves. Turns out it didn't support Multipart/Form-Data type requests.

Switched to http-proxy and everything resolved itself.

The node module Bouncy **DOES NOT** support Multipart/Form-Data requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can don't change your code. Simply send to the client urls of images when you loads all posts.

**The scenario will be like this:**

1) You upload image with simple POST request.

2) After this running AJAX call to get all posts for instance "/posts".

3) The controller returns all posts for example : `[{ id: 1, text: "asd", image: "yourhost.com/images/image.png"}, ...]`

4) Using your jquery or other things you reload view.